# Display a cross from its center

Tags: javascript, canvas

The following code allows me to click on an image (canvas), have coordinates, and place a cross exactly where the click was done. The problem with the cross, that it will be represented from the corner (right-bottom) and i will have an offset between the click and the cross, that do not represent the exact coordinate. In other words, the center of the cross should be the origin of dislaying the coordinates.

How to do that ?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "image.png";

 //Declare Marker sprite
var Marker = function () {
    this.Sprite = new Image();
    this.Sprite.src = "cross.png"
    this.Width = 10;
    this.Height = 10;
    this.XPos = 0;
    this.YPos = 0;
}

var Markers = new Array();

var mouseClicked = function (mouse) {
    // Get corrent mouse coords
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseXPos = Math.round(mouse.x - rect.left);
    var mouseYPos = Math.round(mouse.y - rect.top);

    console.log("Marker added");

    // Move the marker when placed to a better location
    var marker = new Marker();
    marker.XPos = mouseXPos - (marker.Width / 2);
    marker.YPos = mouseYPos - marker.Height;
    marker.YPosNew = marker.YPos;
    Markers.push(marker);

    // Draw marker
    context.drawImage(Markers[0].Sprite, Markers[0].XPos, Markers[0].YPos, Markers[0].Width, Markers[0].Height);
    // Calculate postion text
    var markerText = Markers[0].XPos + ", " + Markers[0].YPosNew;


    // disable pointer after 1s
    setTimeout( function(){ 
    document.getElementById('Canvas').style.cursor="not-allowed";  }  , 1000 );
}

// Add mouse click event listener to canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClicked, false);

var main = function () {
    draw();
};

var draw = function () {
    // Clear Canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw diagramme
    context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 954, 267);
    //draw all precedent cross
    cross = new Image();
    cross.src = "cross.png";

}
mapSprite.addEventListener('load', main);
```

```html
<div style="width : 75%;margin : auto;">
    <canvas id="Canvas" width="954" height="267"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var marker = new Marker();
marker.XPos = mouseXPos - (marker.Width / 2);
marker.YPos = mouseYPos - (marker.Height / 2);
marker.YPosNew = marker.YPos;
Markers.push(marker);
```

change your marker's Ypos , that's why its going up. in this case cross will position at middle of click.